# how to create rest API for .py file which connects to MySql

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, pycharm

I have already created 2 .py files. one is connecting to MySql (dbconnect.py) and the other (app.py) is calling functions defined in the first file.

I have uploaded my files on GitHub repository https://github.com/omkarcpatilgithub/Moneytor.

can anyone help me creating a rest API for the 1st file (dbconnect.py) with Django?
I have no idea about Django framework, what should I actually do or where I should start?

Comment: Start with the [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/) , and think about the structure of questions and polls, like rooms and booking. With this as a base do the [django rest tutorial](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/#quickstart), and add the api for the model generated in step one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it you should start with the Django tutorials. Your code repositories shows that you are trying to do things that is already boilerplate w/ django.. **For example**

- Django has a settings.py where you can define there database connection
- Django has ORM instead of creating functions on how SQL queries get executed